# JavaScript error: 'contest' is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm making a simple rock paper scissors game in JavaScript, but I keep running into an error where when I call a function, it keeps returning that it isn't one. Any help would be appreciated! I'm sure I'm just putting into the wrong spot or I'm not passing variables in correctly. Or I've tried moving it around and I've tried not passing variables into it, but it keeps giving me the same error code.

```js
var playGame = function() {
  var playerChoice = window.prompt("Choose your weapon! Enter r for Rock, p for paper, or s for Scissors.");
  console.log(playerChoice)
  switch (playerChoice) {
    case "r":
      console.log("Player chooses Rock!");
      break;
    case "p":
      console.log("Player chooses Paper!");
      break;
    case "s":
      console.log("Player chooses Scissors!");
      break;
    default:
      window.alert("You did not pick a valid option. Try again.");
      playGame();
      break;
  };
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  console.log(randomNum);
  var compChoice = "";
  switch (randomNum) {
    case 1:
      compChoice = "r";
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
    case 2:
      compChoice = "p";
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
    case 3:
      compChoice = "s"
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
  };
  contest(playerChoice, compChoice);
};

var playConfirm = window.confirm("Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
if (playConfirm) {
  playGame();
} else {
  alert("Ok, maybe next time. Have a nice day!");
}
var contest = function(pChoice, cChoice) {
  // for () {
  switch (pChoice, cChoice) {
    case (pChoice === cChoice):
      window.alert("It's a tie!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "r") && (cChoice = "p"):
      window.alert("I won! Paper covers rock!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "r") && (cChoice = "s"):
      window.alert("You won! Rock crushes scissors!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "p") && (cChoice = "r"):
      window.alert("You won! Paper covers rock!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "p") && (cChoice = "s"):
      window.alert("I won! Scissors cuts paper!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "s") && (cChoice = "r"):
      window.alert("I won! Rock crushes scissors!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "s") && (cChoice = "p"):
      window.alert("You won! Scissors cuts paper!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: You are getting the error because you are calling `playGame` (which calls `contest`) before the function was assigned to `contest`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have used `contest` function before definition.

If you move the `contest` function definition before usage, it will work.

```js
var contest = function (pChoice, cChoice) {
  // for () {
  switch (pChoice, cChoice) {
    case (pChoice === cChoice):
      window.alert("It's a tie!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "r") && (cChoice = "p"):
      window.alert("I won! Paper covers rock!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "r") && (cChoice = "s"):
      window.alert("You won! Rock crushes scissors!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "p") && (cChoice = "r"):
      window.alert("You won! Paper covers rock!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "p") && (cChoice = "s"):
      window.alert("I won! Scissors cuts paper!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "s") && (cChoice = "r"):
      window.alert("I won! Rock crushes scissors!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
    case (pChoice = "s") && (cChoice = "p"):
      window.alert("You won! Scissors cuts paper!");
      // playAgain();
      break;
  }
};

var playGame = function() {
  var playerChoice = window.prompt("Choose your weapon! Enter r for Rock, p for paper, or s for Scissors.");
  console.log(playerChoice)
  switch (playerChoice) {
    case "r":
      console.log("Player chooses Rock!");
      break;
    case "p":
      console.log("Player chooses Paper!");
      break;
    case "s":
      console.log("Player chooses Scissors!");
      break;
    default:
      window.alert("You did not pick a valid option. Try again.");
      playGame();
      break;
  };
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  console.log(randomNum);
  var compChoice = "";
  switch (randomNum) {
    case 1:
      compChoice = "r";
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
    case 2:
      compChoice = "p";
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
    case 3:
      compChoice = "s"
      console.log(compChoice);
      break;
  };
  contest(playerChoice, compChoice);
};

var playConfirm = window.confirm("Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
if (playConfirm) {
  playGame();
} else {
  alert("Ok, maybe next time. Have a nice day!");
}
```

Comment: I added my answer to the bottom, which also works. So why moving the ```window.confirm``` fixed I wonder?

Comment: That depends on the point of the function call. When you put `playConfirm` above `contest`, till the user input on the prompt, the `contest` definition part won't be called.
So it will be undefined and failed to call.

But after you've moved the `playConfirm` under contest, this means, after contest definition run, the `prompt` will be shown. So the function will be existed.

Comment: @4156: You're answer is exactly the same as this one. You didn't just move `window.confirm`, you also moved the `playGame()` function call. Moving those lines "to the bottom" and moving the `context` declaration "to the top" yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, moving the

```
var playConfirm = window.confirm("Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
if (playConfirm) {
  playGame();
} else {
  alert("Ok, maybe next time. Have a nice day!");
}
```

to the bottom fixed it, maybe has something to do with how it calls functions?